# Does Socket.AcceptAsync require and 'End' method call

Tags: c#, sockets

Reading the MSDN documentation for Socket.AcceptAsync I am still not entirely clear if there is a complimentary 'End' method.

So, in the case of BeginAccept() there is an EndAccept() method that completes the call and takes the IAsyncResult as a parameter, allowing the developer access to the Socket (via the IAsyncResult.AsyncState method). Calling EndAccept (or any other Endxxx method pair) internally cleans up some CLR allocated resources, as well as providing functionality to monitor if an asynchronous operation actually completed/errored etc.

All this leads me to the question of whether there is a need to call an End method following a call to AcceptAsync - or ReceiveAsync for that matter? Or are their End methods neatly wrapped up within the Async, perhaps as a Task and ContinueWith? Hence why a SocketAsyncEventArgs contains the Socket itself.

If anyone knows then brilliant! Many thanks!

Comment: MSDN doesn't really include an example with the brief details of Socket.AcceptAsync, but there's more info and an extensive example for the associated [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx). could that be of any help to you?

Comment: Hi, yeah I found that was a much better source of info than the actual MSDN article on AcceptAsync. It didn't answer my question fully (infact probably added to it :-)) but between the two and the example code it helped a lot! Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with a bit more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are no End method.

You should handle the `Completed` event in the `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. Also note that `ReceiveAsync` etc can complete directly (and therefore not trigger the event).

**Update**

> Hence why a SocketAsyncEventArgs contains the Socket itself.

It's because you should be able to handle IO operations for all clients in the same class. You also have a `UserToken` property which can be used to store client specific information.

> Or are their End methods neatly wrapped up within the Async, perhaps as a Task and ContinueWith

No. The new Async model are more like the "real" model (IO Completion ports) which are provided by Windows. The Begin/End kind of structure was introduced to make the asynchronous programming easier. The XxxxAsync model was created to get even better performance for those applications that need it (imho there are a few that will benefit from it, but it's really important for those)

Comment: Hi jgauffin, many thanks for the extra info. Very much apreciated!! I shall be dusting off Mark Russinovich's 5th tome to have a proper indepth read about I/O completion ports.